# Capybara features outside of /features directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I have some large end-to-end integration tests that for CI purposes I don't want in my spec/features folder in Capybara.  Instead I have them in a spec/integration folder.  Knowing that Capybara loads differently based on the folder, I put the :type=>:feature option on my describe, like so:

```
describe 'Recurring Contract Orders', :type=>:feature, :js=>true, :focus=>true do
    it "satisifies the use case" do
    ....
```

But no luck, I am still getting the:

```
NameError:
   undefined local variable or method `page' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x007fd396bd2998>
```

error when I run the test.  Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: Can you share the integration setup/spec_helper files?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's something you are still trying to solve, but I was having the same problem.  You are able to use the specific Capybara commands if you just include the DSL:

```
include Capybara::DSL
```

I haven't found out how to just have Capybara include my /integration folder yet, but this has worked for now.

Answer (score 0):

For future ref, I think the right thing (according to https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) is to tag the specs with :type => :feature, e.g.

```ruby
describe "Some pages", :type => :feature do

  specify "some behaviour"

end
```